# function fetch() on a non-object in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I have this url,

```
http://webworks.net/ww.incs/forgotten-password-verification.php?verification_code=974bf747124c69f12ae3b36afcaccc68&email=myemail@gmail.com&redirect=/ww.admin/index.php
```

And this gives the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
/var/www/webworks/ww.incs/basics.php on line 23 
Call Stack: 0.0005 338372 1. {main}() 
/var/www/webworks/ww.incs/forgotten-password-verification.php:
0 0.0020 363796 2. dbRow() 
/var/www/webworks/ww.incs/forgotten-password-verification.php:18
```

The forgotten-password-verification.php

```
require 'login-libs.php';

login_check_is_email_provided();

// check that a verification code was provided
if(
 !isset($_REQUEST['verification_code']) || $_REQUEST['verification_code']==''
){
 login_redirect($url,'novalidation');
}

// check that the email/verification code combination matches a row in the user table
// $password=md5($_REQUEST['email'].'|'.$_REQUEST['password']);
$r=dbRow('select * from user_accounts where
 email="'.addslashes($_REQUEST['email']).'" and
 verification_code="'.$_REQUEST['verification_code'].'" and active'
);
if($r==false){
 login_redirect($url,'validationfailed');
}

// success! set the session variable, then redirect
$_SESSION['userdata']=$r;
$groups=json_decode($r['groups']);
$_SESSION['userdata']['groups']=array();
foreach($groups as $g)$_SESSION['userdata']['groups'][$g]=true;
if($r['extras']=='')$r['extras']='[]';
$_SESSION['userdata']['extras']=json_decode($r['extras']);

login_redirect($url);
```

And login-libs,

```
require 'basics.php';

$url='/';
$err=0;

function login_redirect($url,$msg='success'){
 if($msg)$url.='?login_msg='.$msg;
 header('Location: '.$url);
 echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'">redirect</a>';
 exit;
}

// set up the redirect
if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])){
 $url=preg_replace('/[\?\&].*/','',$_REQUEST['redirect']);
 if($url=='')$url='/';
}

// check that the email address is provided and valid
function login_check_is_email_provided(){
 if(
  !isset($_REQUEST['email']) || $_REQUEST['email']==''
  || !filter_var($_REQUEST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
 ){
  login_redirect($GLOBALS['url'],'noemail');
 }
}

// check that the captcha is provided
function login_check_is_captcha_provided(){
 if(
   !isset($_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) || $_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]==''
  || !isset($_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]) || $_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]==''
 ){
  login_redirect($GLOBALS['url'],'nocaptcha');
 }
}

// check that the captcha is valid
function login_check_is_captcha_valid(){
 require 'recaptcha.php';
 $resp=recaptcha_check_answer(
  RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE,
  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
  $_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
  $_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]
 );
 if(!$resp->is_valid){
  login_redirect($GLOBALS['url'],'invalidcaptcha');
 }
}
```

basics.php is,

```
session_start();
function __autoload($name) {
 require $name . '.php';
}
function dbInit(){
 if(isset($GLOBALS['db']))return $GLOBALS['db'];
 global $DBVARS;
 $db=new PDO('mysql:host='.$DBVARS['hostname'].';dbname='.$DBVARS['db_name'],$DBVARS['username'],$DBVARS['password']);
 $db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
 $db->num_queries=0;
 $GLOBALS['db']=$db;
 return $db;
}
function dbQuery($query){
 $db=dbInit();
 $q=$db->query($query);
 $db->num_queries++;
 return $q;
}
function dbRow($query) {
 $q = dbQuery($query);
 return $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
define('SCRIPTBASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/');
require SCRIPTBASE . '.private/config.php';
if(!defined('CONFIG_FILE'))define('CONFIG_FILE',SCRIPTBASE.'.private/config.php');
set_include_path(SCRIPTBASE.'ww.php_classes'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

I am not sure how to solve the problem.

My db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` text,
  `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `groups` text,
  `activation_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extras` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `active`, `groups`, `activation_key`, `extras`) VALUES
(2, 'bla@blabla.com', '6d24dde9d56b9eab99a303a713df2891', 1, '["_superadministrators"]', '5d50e39420127d0bab44a56612f2d89b', NULL),
(3, 'user@blabla.com', 'e83052ab33df32b94da18f6ff2353e94', 1, '[]', NULL, NULL),
(9, 'myemail@gmail.com', '9ca3eee3c43384a575eb746eeae0f279', 1, '["_superadministrators"]', '974bf747124c69f12ae3b36afcaccc68', NULL);
```

Comment: It seems your dbQuery() did not return an object. Use `var_dump()` on $q to see what it is...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, I believe, in this:

the table `user_accounts`:

```
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` text,
    `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
    `groups` text,
    `activation_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `extras` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

and

the 'forgotten-password-verification.php':

```
    // check that the email/verification code combination matches a row in the user table
    // $password=md5($_REQUEST['email'].'|'.$_REQUEST['password']);
    $r=dbRow('select * from user_accounts where
    email="'.addslashes($_REQUEST['email']).'" and
    verification_code="'.$_REQUEST['verification_code'].'" and active'
    );
```

where `verification_code` is not a valid part of `user_accounts`.
Change it and it should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Line 23 of `basics.php` is probably:

```
return $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This means that `$q` is not the object you expected it to be (seems like a PDOStatement). Apparently, it is returned from the `dbQuery` function, which returns the result of `PDO::query`. `PDO::query` will return a PDOStatement on success, or FALSE on error.

It means that you query is erroneous. Most likely this one:

```
$r=dbRow('select * from user_accounts where
 email="'.addslashes($_REQUEST['email']).'" and
 verification_code="'.$_REQUEST['verification_code'].'" and active'
);
```

The problem is probably the end of your query, which does not look like valid SQL:

```
and active
```

Also, since you are using PDO, you should take advantage of prepared statements, since your code is actually open to SQL injection. `addslashes` is not a proper mechanism for escaping database parameters, and you should not use `$_REQUEST` unless you know what you are doing. You should use `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` directly.

For your securing your queries, use prepared statements, and check the return values:

```
function dbQuery($query, array $params = array()){
 $db=dbInit();
 $q=$db->prepare($query); // use prepare() instead of query()
 $q->execute($params);    // automatically bind the parameters with execute()
 $db->num_queries++;
 return $q;
}
function dbRow($query, array $params = array()) {
 $q = dbQuery($query, $params);
 if (!$q) {
    // check for errors
    throw new Exception('A database error has occured!');
 }
 return $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then just do:

```
$r=dbRow('select * from user_accounts where email=? and verification_code=?',
   array($_GET['email'], $_GET['verification_code'])
);
```

Comment: Thanks for prepared statement. And I took active part, but it still does not work. Mmmm...

Comment: Use [PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/pdo.errorinfo) to find out what error your database is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `password_reminder.php`.

In stead of `verificatio_code`, it was using `activation_code`.